# (Javascript) Creating a tree from an array which contains paths

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, path, tree

I have an array, lets say

```
arr = [Service1/Folder1//file, Service2/Folder2/Sub//data];
```

and the task would be to somehow create a tree out of this.

It could be done using "ul" or "li" HTML Tags. I also have to say that I had a JSON Object to begin with, and i converted the JSON Object into the array with the paths.

Note, that //means that we are in the last subfolder and after // the file is shown.

I sort of had an idea to somehow loop through it, and check if the array contains more than once the word lets say "Folder1" and if yes, than Folder1 must be an "li". But it doesnt work.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you tell us what is the example of result you need ?

Comment: Like i said I would need to have a tree with the stuff...An example would be the directory tree you see in Windows. You go to C:\ and then you see all the folders...I would need such a visual representation of the hierachy as well. (HTML ul,li tags)